# Unable to commit code to google code with Tortoise SVN: Authentication Fails

Tags: tortoisesvn, google-code

I am trying to commit some updates to my personal project on google code and get prompted for the user and password as expected.  When I enter what I know is the valid user and password it fails with the following error:

Commit
Commit failed (details follow):
MKACTIVITY of '/svn/!svn/act/9a2c12c9-9adf-5d48-85da-616bfe91e95f': 
authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic 
challenge (https://jaysmith.googlecode.com)

My password does have some special characters in it but works for logging into Google Reader, and other Google services.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try changing your password to leave out these special characters temporarily as a test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get a special password to use with the repository. It won't be your regular google password

Comment: Thanks, You can tell I don't use this too much.  I had to regenerate the password once I found it but it worked.

Thanks!